# displaying context specific errors on an eCommerce checkout process?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

Running an eCommerce site developed using MVC architecture with C# and SQL db. 
We have a generic message displayed to users if they entered a wrong billing address or wrong credit card information - "Unable to process the order. Please check billing and credit details and try again".

Is it possible to display the actual mistake. For example: "Unrecognized CVV number" or "The name entered does not match the credit card information entered".

If possible what does it take to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do this. This is a severe security hole which allows people to attempt to use stolen information and guess pieces they aren't aware of, the CVV number is only 3 numbers, if you tell them that's the incorrect piece then they can easily guess to get it right.

Tell them exactly what you have right now, that is the secure way to do this, to ensure people are not using your e-commerce system for theft.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking too! I think we might just go with the generic error we have. Thanks!!

Comment: @user1266515 it's an easy trap to fall in because you want to present the most user friendly system to your customers, but sometimes you have to really imagine how user friendly you're making it to those with ill intent as well. :)

Comment: Just an aftrethought: Is it possible that I could atleast tell the user whether the correction is with the credit card info or the billing info?

Comment: @user1266515 "The billing info you entered does not match the Credit Card's" means "You have completely valid credit card information, now just find out this persons Address, or use a site which does not validate address in it's billing system."

Comment: I just took a look at ebay's site. Here are the two cases I tested: When I put in a valid credit card but a bad billing address the error message read "We did not find a nilling address that matched this credit card info" and when I entered wrong credit info but the correct billing address the error read "This is an invalid credit card number"??

Comment: @user1266515 The level of security you want is up to you, I won't say you shouldn't do it that way, you definitely shouldn't do it with the CVV number, but beyond that I'm just trying to raise the point. At the end of the day, nothing is COMPLETELY secure, so you have to weigh your options.

Comment: I completely udnerstand, besides the number of users who get the information wrong is not going to be very significant. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you follow something like [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript) I think you will get your desired result.  Using `DataAnnotations` you should be able to get most of your validation working.  If there is any server-side validation you need, then you can add to the model errors with `ModelState.AddModelError` inside your controller.  These errors will then show up in your UI if you use the validation helpers (`@Html.ValidationMessageFor`).